# Why Request is null in my controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I call a a methode by HttpPost in my ServiceController from my View `http://localhost/Case/Form`

My serviceController class:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
[...]

namespace ApnNephro.WebUI.Controllers
{
    public class ServicesController : Controller
    {
        public string GetDomain()
        {
            string url = "";
            try
            {
                string _url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
                int _si = (_url.IndexOf("//"));
                int _fi = (_url.Substring(_si + 2)).IndexOf("/"); // first /
                url = _url.Substring(0, _fi + _si + 2);
                return url.ToString();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ioe)
            {
                throw new Exception(ioe.Message + " / " + ioe.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {    
                throw new Exception(e.Message + " / " + e.StackTrace);
            }
            return url.ToString();
        }

[...]
```

And i call him in my MailHelper.cs :

```
private static string domain = new ServicesController().GetDomain();
```

But an exception occure because Request is null...

So, my Question is, why Request is null ?
Is it assigned only in the current view controller, so here in my CaseController only ?

Comment: Please don't repeat tags in question titles. It's duplicate infomation.

Comment: if you find yourself creating a new `Controller` instance, then: you're doing something very wrong (unless you happen to be writing a custom controller-factory); you simply *aren't meant to be doing that*. The new `Controller` will not be correctly configured. Have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Request` instead?

Comment: You have right, of course ! I m tired i think ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new controller, that is not associated with a request.
Instead of putting the get domain in a controller and then creating a new one,
You can just access the current request via the `HttpContext.Current.Request`. 
This is also available in a static method.